# Conda Virtual Environment Packages

Tags: python, pip, conda, miniconda

Lately I've been using `conda` instead of `virtualenv` and I think I like it better, except when I install packages I don't think they are only installed into my virtual environment.

If I run `pip freeze` within my virtual environment I get the list of packages installed, no surprise there. However, when I deactivate the virtual environment and run `pip freeze` again, I get the same list. Is my environment not separated from my base distro? Plus, how do I create a clean environment if my packages are shared across all environments?

Note: I noticed this after installing packages with pip using `pip setup.py install` within a package. However, according to [the docs](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment) you can use pip in a conda virtual environment.

Comment: are you really sure that the `pip` inside your virtualenv is the one you installed for the `virtualenv`. the doc also says you to do this: `conda install -n myenv pip` to use pip inside virutalenv.

Comment: Have you activated the environment using `conda activate myenv`?

Comment: @jalazbe yes I definitely did that

Comment: @user2906838 ohhhh I don't think I did that, maybe that was the issue. I just went ahead and used pip.

Comment: yes, that could be, check.

Comment: @user2906838 so I installed pip in a new virtual envelope using the method you mentioned, but when I use 'pip freeze' it shows all of the packages I've installed in my base environment. Is that normal?

Comment: Your pip packages might have been installed to ~/.local